# Unable to update file in appDataFolder using Google Drive REST API V3 on Android

Tags: google-drive-api

This is the code i'm using to update the file.

```
File metadata = generateFileMetadata(fileId, thumbnail, properties);
return mService.files().update(fileId, metadata, generateFileContents())
                    .setFields("id, name, appProperties")
                    .execute();
```

This code generates a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setInitiationRequestMethod(MediaHttpUploader.java:872)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.initializeMediaUpload(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:237)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Update.<init>(Drive.java:3163)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files.update(Drive.java:3113)
```

Using breakpoints I could see that the String passed to the `setInitiationRequestMethod` is `PATCH` (not `POST` or `PUT`):

```
public MediaHttpUploader setInitiationRequestMethod(String initiationRequestMethod) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(initiationRequestMethod.equals(HttpMethods.POST)
    || initiationRequestMethod.equals(HttpMethods.PUT));
    this.initiationRequestMethod = initiationRequestMethod;
    return this;
  }
```

this is what i have in my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.21.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev11-1.21.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
```

if I remove the file content (generateFileContents()) I'm able to update the metadata just fine.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [current commit](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/commit/172dfb85fead485163524c190dda0a31836af9c5) of the google-api-java-client.
Unfortunately the fix was not released yet (fix on 21 Nov 2015 vs release on 19 Nov 2015), so you may have to build locally the project (with maven for instance)

Comment: You're right. Apparently it's a bug. Google's own API pages link to a different issue tracker but the one on GitHub has the bug report: [issue #994](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/994)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this bug while writing a Drive REST API integration for an Android app (with Android Studio/Gradle). Since I'm not particularly experienced with Android's build system, resolving the issue cost me a few hours. Maybe this helps somebody with the same problem:

1. Clone the `google-api-java-client` repo from GitHub https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client
2. Install Maven https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/ (e.g. `brew install maven` on OSX)
3. On the command line, change into the `google-api-client` sub dir of the repo you cloned above
4. Run `mvn clean install`
5. This will produce a subdir called `target` in the `google-api-client` directory
6. In there, find `google-api-client-1.22.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, rename it to `google-api-client-1.21.00.jar` (the renaming is probably not needed)
7. Drop the .jar in the `libs` folder of your android project
8. Tell Gradle to ignore the google-api-client dependency of the libraries you use, in my case this was:

   ```
   compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.21.0') {
       exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
       exclude module: 'google-api-client'
   }
   compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev14-1.21.0') {
       exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
       exclude module: 'google-api-client'
   }
   ```
9. Add the Jackson dependency again, in case you miss it now. Do the same with other google-api-java-client dependencies if you need them.

   ```
   compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.21.0'){
       exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
   }
   ```
10. Build your project, `update(...)` should now work.
11. Make a note to scrap these changes once Google has updated the library.

Answer (score 0):

The [MediaHttpUploader](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.18.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/media/MediaHttpUploader.html#setInitiationRequestMethod(java.lang.String)) javadocs suggests that it will only be  used for HttpMethods#POST, and HttpMethods#UPDATE. Using `update`, based on the [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) resource, indicates its using a `PATCH` method - leading to the `IllegalArgumentException`.

The overridden `update` method should only be used if you're uploading media content.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. That's exactly what I'm trying to use the update method for. the docs say the update method "Updates a file's metadata **and/or content with patch** semantics."

It doesn't say anything about the file's resource. it's always PATCH. 

I don't see any other way to update a file's contents. (other than deleting and recreating the file).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exception in a Desktop application.
Instead, using the Drive Api V2, the update goes well.