# Update file in google drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to create spreadsheet file in my google drive folder, and if it already exists in directory to update it. New file creation works fine, but I couldn't update the existing file. What I am doing wrong?

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setInitiationRequestMethod(MediaHttpUploader.java:872)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.initializeMediaUpload(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:237)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Update.<init>(Drive.java:3155)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files.update(Drive.java:3105)
    at DriveQuickstart$2.visitFile(DriveQuickstart.java:248)
```

My code:

```
    Drive.Files.Update u = service.files().update(id, new File(), new FileContent("text/csv", path.toFile()));
    File f = u.execute();
```

Comment: The bug was in google-api-client. [See this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35963590/4937463)