# How to update already existing file in google drive api v3 java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have tried with the following code... Without any luck...

```
private void updateFile(Drive service, String fileId) {
        try {
            File file = new File(); /********/
            final java.io.File fileToUpdate = new java.io.File("D:/Work Data/Files/pdf.pdf");
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/pdf", fileToUpdate);
            file = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();
            System.out.println(fileId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (isDebug) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
    }
```

also tried with...

```
 private void updateFile(Drive service, String fileId) {
        try {
            File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute(); /********/
            final java.io.File fileToUpdate = new java.io.File("D:/Work Data/Files/pdf.pdf");
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/pdf", fileToUpdate);
            file = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();
            System.out.println(fileId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (isDebug) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
    }
```

With every time i execute the code i get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setInitiationRequestMethod(MediaHttpUploader.java:872)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.initializeMediaUpload(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:237)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Update.<init>(Drive.java:3163)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files.update(Drive.java:3113)
    at com.test.DriveTester.updateFile(DriveTester.java:76)
    at com.test.DriveTester.main(DriveTester.java:64)
```

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong ? Any sample code for this i.e. updating the content of an already existing file on google drive will be helpful...

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: sorry but not yet... for my purpose i wan okay with deleting the file and re-adding it...

Answer (score 8):

For API v3 the solution proposed by Android Enthusiast does not work unfortunately.
The issue is with this bit:

```
 // First retrieve the file from the API.
File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();
```

doing this it will create a File object, with it's ID field being set, when executing the update, itt will throw an exception, since the ID meta field is not editable directly.

What you can do is simply create a new file:

```
File file = new File();
```

alter the meta you'd like and update file content if required as shown in the example.

then simply update the file as proposed above:

```
// Send the request to the API.
File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();
```

So based a full example would look like this based on Android Enthusiast solution:

```
private static File updateFile(Drive service, String fileId, String newTitle,
String newDescription, String newMimeType, String newFilename, boolean newRevision) {
try {
// First create a new File.
File file = new File();

// File's new metadata.
file.setTitle(newTitle);
file.setDescription(newDescription);
file.setMimeType(newMimeType);

// File's new content.
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(newFilename);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(newMimeType, fileContent);

// Send the request to the API.
File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();

return updatedFile;
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
return null;
}
}
```

Comment: I need to create google doc from html file. Doc file page orientation should be landscape in order to fit tables from html. I am creating empty google doc, changing its document style to landscape, then updating file using similar code like above. But when updating the page orientation comes back to portrait. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You don't have to create new file's metadata. You can just set the `file` param to `null` and overwrite only the file content. `File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, null, mediaContent).execute();`

Answer (score 4):

I can share javascript code for uploading to an already existing file using v3

```
    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '?uploadType=media';
if(self.fetch){
var setHeaders = new Headers();
setHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken.access_token);
setHeaders.append('Content-Type', mime);

var setOptions = {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: setHeaders,
    body:  data 
};
fetch(url,setOptions)
    .then(response => { if(response.ok){
    console.log("save to drive");
    }
            else{
                console.log("Response wast not ok");
            }
              })
    .catch(error => {
    console.log("There is an error " + error.message);
    });
```

Comment: You are right for the js part of the code but i wan to do this in java as i am doing it server side..

Comment: Thank you for sharing this because Google sends people here who do not have the exact needs as the OP. You did not deserve the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

To update files content, you can use [`Files:update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update), this method supports an /upload URI and accepts uploaded media with the following characteristics:

- Maximum file size: 5120GB
- Accepted Media MIME types: /

This method provides media upload functionality through two separate URIs. For more details, see the document on media upload.

- Upload URI, for media upload requests:

> PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/fileId
>   * Metadata URI, for metadata-only requests:
>
> PUT https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId

```
private static File updateFile(Drive service, String fileId, String newTitle,
String newDescription, String newMimeType, String newFilename, boolean newRevision) {
try {
// First retrieve the file from the API.
File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

// File's new metadata.
file.setTitle(newTitle);
file.setDescription(newDescription);
file.setMimeType(newMimeType);

// File's new content.
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(newFilename);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(newMimeType, fileContent);

// Send the request to the API.
File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();

return updatedFile;
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
return null;
}
}
```

You may also check this [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686284/unable-to-update-file-in-appdatafolder-using-google-drive-rest-api-v3-on-android), the ticket discuss the said error.

Comment: I am using drive api v3 and the above solution doesn't works in that

Comment: In this case you are writing to the fields that are not writable. File file should be created in another way

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/deprecation/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/driveapimigration/DriveServiceHelper.java)

Unlike the other answers, this solution allows you to upload without having to create a file for the data on the device first.

```
 // Create a File containing any metadata changes.
 File metadata = new File().setName(name);

 // Convert content to an AbstractInputStreamContent instance.
 ByteArrayContent contentStream = ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain", content);

// Update the metadata and contents.
mDriveService.files().update(fileId, metadata, contentStream).execute();
```