# How do I update a folder with Google Drive API in Android?

Tags: java, android, file-io, google-drive-api, insert-update

I'm trying to use the Google Drive files.update method in Java to update a folder. By update, I mean replace all the contents with whatever the contents that the new folder has. This is the method I'm using:

```
public Task<String> updateFile(String fileId, String filePath) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            try {
                File file = new File();
                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filePath);

                file.setName(fileContent.getName());
                file.setMimeType("application/octet-stream");

                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/octet-stream", fileContent);

                File updatedFile = mDriveService.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();


                return updatedFile.getId();

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("tag",e.getMessage());

                return null;
            }

        });
    }
```

Bear in mind that this method works with regular non-folder files. I've tried replacing "octet-stream" with the Google Drive folder mime type, getting the same error. The error I get is "/storage/emulated/0/Download/folder (Is a directory)" verbatim, with whatever folder's file path.

Comment: You should write to file not to folders.

Comment: look for this one :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686284/unable-to-update-file-in-appdatafolder-using-google-drive-rest-api-v3-on-android

Comment: As Scary Wombat has said you should not try to upload any information to a folder. Only a name and the MIME type. What line are you getting the error at? And also what is what you are trying to update? the name of the folder? If you don really want to change anything, skip the folders from executing this function.